# Colorbox not working in new content type

Tags: javascript

I have Colorbox and the plugin installed, and enabled.

[image]

The module is in the `sites/all/modules` folder, and the plugin is in the `sites/all/libraries` folder.

I've created a new content type and called it *Image Gallery*.

[image]

I've created a new field for that content type also called *Image Gallery*

[image]

The display format for my Image Gallery field is set to *Colorbox*.

[image]

I can create an image gallery, but the images are not opening in Colorbox. I'm stuck, the console isn't showing any errors, as far as I know everything is configured right but it's not displaying properly. What am I missing?

Comment: First, you can check your console for any errors. Sometimes it is due to jquery version conflicts which causes the problem. Try jQuery Update module and switch to different jQuery versions and see if it works for you.

Comment: @echo - The jQuery Update module did the trick. My install of Drupal is just the automatic GoDaddy install of drupal (probably should have mentioned that in the question), which I know doesn't provide the most recent releases of everything. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

[JQueryUpdate Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) solved the problem.

> It Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of
>   jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might occur because the path to library is incorrectly set. It is typically like so:

```
libraries\colorbox\jquery.colorbox-min.js
```

Though via /admin/config/media/colorbox it is possible to set some other path for it (within 'advanced settings').

There was a time (some older version in colorbox) that the solution was to correct the path to the Colorbox plugin directory, so that after unpacking it looked like so:

```
sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js
```

Refer to [issue #1906156](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906156) for more details on this.

If that doesn't help, then check if there are any other modules that use Colorbox that are trying to find it on this path.

Of course, make sure also that the "permissions" to the plugin are set correctly (if no read access is granted, then that is probably what is causing the problem).